# Email service recommendations that allow masking

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

One thing as a developer that I've ran into many times is when the website needs to respond to user interactions via email with auto responders.  The hang-up is usually trying to get non-technical people to get me the settings needed to send the email.

I personally use gmail business services and have a development email account.  The downfall , after researching it, seems like gmail doesn't allow you to change the from email address.

**I'm looking for recommendations of email services that will either allow masking the from email address and display name.  Or maybe there is another solution technically I'm unaware of.**

*Here is the code I typically use:*

```
// Create message
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toAddress))
    {
         message.To.Add(toAddress);
    }

    message.Body = body;
    message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw (exp);
        }
        finally
        {
            message.Dispose();
        }
    return true;
}
```